# ddev with RaspberryPi 4 and Ubuntu Server 22?

Tags: ubuntu, arm, raspberry-pi4, ddev

I got some new Raspberry Pi 4 with 8GB ram to replace some mini servers that I have in my office network.

Normally I use the Ubuntu Server 22.04 (jammy) on my mini servers and ddev works well. Unfortunatelly this is not the case with the same Ubuntu inside of my new Pi. I was able to install the docker and the mkcert and both are running well but, when I try to install the ddev, I just got the message "Sorry, your machine architecture armv7l is not currently supported."

Am I doing something wrong or there's no port to this set up?

Install the ddev using apt and the install script as well. Both give me the same message.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a 64-bit version of Linux for your Raspberry Pi. As explained below in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76815990/215713 that is a fundamental requirement.

I've been running DDEV on a Raspberry Pi for years, see https://ddev.com/blog/watch-ddev-local-on-arm64-raspberry-pi/

Raspberry Pi is an arm64 processor, so you need to use the arm64 version of DDEV. You can use the linux arm64 version from https://github.com/ddev/ddev/releases

But you didn't say how you were trying to install DDEV... Both `apt install ddev` and the install script should work fine.

Here's what I see with `arch` and `uname -a` on my Pi running Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy:

```
$ arch
aarch64
$ uname -a
Linux pi-ddev-site 5.15.0-1034-raspi #37-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 17 10:02:14 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I probably doing something wrong. I got the arm version to install into my Pi but the package insist to tell me that my architecture isn't an ARM :)


`$ sudo dpkg -i ./ddev_1.22.0_linux_arm64.deb 
[sudo] password for p: 
dpkg: error processing archive ./ddev_1.22.0_linux_arm64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (arm64) does not match system (armhf)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ./ddev_1.22.0_linux_arm64.deb
`
Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you have a different kind of processor. My Raspberry Pi has been fine for ages. Raspberry Pi 4. What does `uname -a` say?

Comment: I updated the answer to show what `arch` and `uname -a` show on my Pi

Comment: Ah, now we know the answer. @pmichelazzo needs to install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks Nate

Comment: Yes, you're right. The mistake was the OS version. 32-bit instead the 64-bit. Problem solved. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Linux treats 32-bit ARM and 64-bit ARM as separate architectures.  32-bit appears as `armhf`, `armv7`, `aarch32`, etc.  64-bit is usually called `arm64` or `aarch64`.  The Raspberry Pi 4's CPU supports both modes, but you have to select one or the other when you install your operating system.

So it looks like you installed a 32-bit ARM version of Ubuntu, but ddev only supports 64-bit ARM.  Thus you'll have to reinstall the operating system using an `arm64` install image, and then you should be able to install ddev.